# How to externalize standalone.xml?

Tags: java, spring, jboss, wildfly-10, application-server

I am setting up a new server and want to externalize standalone.xml configuration mainly datasource to the properties file so that it can be configured using a properties file. I have used various options like using -P properties flag, still no use. I am using wildfly 10.0 Final.
for example 
from this

```
<connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/local_db?currentSchema=something</connection-url>
```

to this

```
<connection-url>${connection_url}</connection-url>
```

Comment: What is the error that you are facing ?

Comment: I am not having any error, I just want to externalize configuration to the properties file . As I don't want other developers to access the standalone.xml and accidentally mess up the configuration.

Comment: With the `-P` argument you just pass a properties file so you'd have an entry like `connection_url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/local_db?currentSchema=something`. I'm not too sure what the actual question is here. Or really what "externalize" means in this context.

Answer (score 0):

To  in JBoss you could create a properties file and execute a cli command to read it, for example, creating your datasource.

### File

Example of datasource property file:

```
set ds=TestDB
set dsName=java:jboss/datasources/$ds
data-source add --name=$ds --jndi-name=$dsName --driver-name=example \
    --connection-url="jdbc:example"\
    --user-name="exampleuser"  --password="examplepassword"
echo 'Success'
reload
```

That can be saved as "file.txt"

### File command

Then execute the following cli command:

```
./jboss-cli.sh --connect --file="file.txt"
```

### Regarding Escape sequence

Be careful regarding the escape sequence, because it changes for the CLI according to the configuration of JBoss and the flag resolve-paramater-values, which if it's set to true tells the CLI to interpret $ instead of just passing it to EAP as is and consequently the escape sequence for --file changes to /$/$.